# XML parsing with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an `xml` document that I have generated from a Fortify scan.  Currently I have a `xml` doc that looks like this:

```
<Chart chartType="table">
    <Axis>Fortify Priority Order</Axis>
    <MajorAttribute>Analysis</MajorAttribute>
    <GroupingSection count="2">
        <groupTitle>High</groupTitle>
    </GroupingSection>
    <GroupingSection count="101">
        <groupTitle>Low</groupTitle>
    </GroupingSection>
    <GroupingSection count="5">
        <groupTitle>Medium</groupTitle>
    </GroupingSection>
</Chart>
```

What I want to do is parse through this doc and pull out the *High*, *Medium*, and *Low* counts and assign them to a variable to pass to another script.

My problem is when I pull the `xml` file into `powershell`, how do I get the count for *High* findings?

Currently script:

```
$xml = [xml](get-content $file)

$xml.GetElementsByTagName('groupTitle') | Select-Object -Property 'High'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way where at the end you will have 3 vars (`$high`, `$low`, `$medium`) :

```
$xml = [xml](get-content $file)
$xml.Chart.GroupingSection | % {Set-Variable -Name $_.groupTitle -Value $_.count}
```

Here is another way where you build an object with 3 properties :

```
$xml = [xml](get-content $file)
$xml.Chart.GroupingSection | % {$a=New-Object PSCustomObject}{Add-Member -InputObject $a -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.groupTitle -Value $_.count}
```

At the end consider `$a` :

```
High Low Medium
---- --- ------
2    101 5
```

so you can write : `$a.High`

Answer (score 3):

You can try using XPath with `SelectSingleNode`:

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//groupTitle[text() = 'High']").ParentNode.Count
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the short version!

Answer (score 1):

other method:

```
[xml] $xml=[xml](gc "c:\temp\file1.xml")
($xml.Chart.GroupingSection | where groupTitle -EQ "High").count
```